# pycallgraph module - No attribute Config

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pycallgraph

After intalling pycallgraph, I had to rename the file to pycallgraph.py on windows, and when running I get the following error message:

pycallgraph -h (for help)
module 'pycallgraph' has no attribute 'Config'

I've got my path variables set up correctly and can run the banana example on the site.

https://pycallgraph.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html